# Variable scoping on asp.net codebehind in c# (hopefully a no brainer!)

Tags: c#, asp.net, scope

I have an asp.net page (C# codebehind), and in page_load there are various linq queries returning anonymous types, such as:

```
var customersAdded = from r in AddedRecords
                                 select new { Ref = r.CustomerRef, Name = r.Customer_Name };
```

On the page I have a button called 'export to excel', and in that buttonClick event I try to refer to customersAdded.  It says it doesn't exist in the context.  I know I've overcome similar issues in the past using things along the lines of:

```
if (File.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Variants/" + GetUserTheme().ToString() + "/images/" + i.ImageUrl)))
```

But haven't had luck so far.

So question is, how to refer to the variable?  And for reference, if I say wanted to refer to a value in a control (eg a textbox on the page) would the same or different approach apply?

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just declared your variable as a local variable to `Page_Load`.  To refer to the variable in any other method, it would at least need to be a member of the class.  Of course, you're using an anonymous type, and the type itself also needs to be in scope.

One way to address the issue would be to declare the type within the class, probably just as an inner struct.  Then, the type is no longer anonymous, so you're free to declare a class member as a collection of your new type.  You can assign to that variable in `Page_Load`, then access the variable elsewhere in your class.

**Edit:**

The variety of "lazy-loading" I am referring to in my comment is not the language feature with the `lazy` keyword, nor anything involving `yield`, etc., but rather just this:

```
private IQueryable<AddedRecord> _customersAdded;

// make this public if you want to access outside the class
private IQueryable<AddedRecord> CustomersAdded
{
    get
    {
        if (_customersAdded == null)
        {
            // replace next statement with the query you need
            _customersAdded = AddedRecords.Where(something);
        }
        return _customersAdded;
    }
}
```

Now, if you need more parameters to make this query happen, you can always populate _customersAdded ahead of time.  This is kind of a trivial example, admittedly.

Comment: Hi Andrew, so with this method, if I have 15 such queries (which I do unfortunately!) would I need to declare them all explicitly at class level to do this?  Perhaps I could convert to arrays or something to avoid the issue?

Comment: @Glinkot Well, there are other options, yes.  First, in your example, you do have an actual type you can use, specifically AddedRecord.  Presumably it has additional fields, but that is at least an alternative to declaring more types.  Second, perhaps you could use a lazy-load strategy for the queries, making each a property that runs the query on the first use of the get accessor, storing the result.  Doing so would allow you to use the query anywhere in your class, even with private accessibility on the properties.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I'm probably not at a level to implement the lazy loading idea though the idea sounds intriguing!  Thanks for your help mate :)

Comment: @Glinkot Sure you are.  See the edit I will be making shortly.

Comment: thanks for the code!  I will give it a whirl.  It does look like I still need to define a type for every query which will add up, but it also sounds like that's by design.  Cheers and thanks for the extra info :)